# Why In iOS 9 and Xcode 7 not show full view height and width in iPhone 6 and above?

Tags: iphone, ios9, xcode7

I am using iOS 9 and Xcode 7 ....and I make new app without storyboard and use auto layout and use size classes.....basically I am using xib with resizing feature and use code to check device . When I was using xcode 6.4 and iOS 8 then my code work for each device . But when I use Xcode 7 and iOS 9 then  screen not show full on device this is only for iPhone 6 and above.  I attached image here...[image]

See In image black part appear on each screen for iPhone 6 and above.....I add all launch images on launch image View....but I don't know why this problem appear.

and If I'm not added launch images and without that run code this view like this....[image]......I this this is problem related to launch screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the launch screen for these devices. or your view background color is black. and you didn't set the constraint for the `UIImageView`.

Comment: I already added launch screen for iPhone portrait iOS 8,9 (Retain HD 5.5 and Retain HD 4.7) and iOS 7-9 (2X and Retain 4).

Comment: are you using nib file for launch screens or images?

Comment: try, to remove the app from device/simulator. clean the project in xcode then re-run the app. when I switched to xcode 7 for one of my projects, some images didn't appear in the app until I changed the name of those images and reset them in the interface builder

Comment: I am added images .  Images.xcassets there are three folder 1. AppIcon.appiconset  2. BrandAsset.launchimage and 3.LaunchImage.launchimage . and In LaunchImage.launchimage I have added all launch images.

Comment: try what I added in comment. may work that's what happen with me.

Comment: I check self.view frame using this ...CGRect frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, PHONE_UISCREEN_WIDTH, PHONE_UISCREEN_HEIGHT);
here #define PHONE_UISCREEN_WIDTH            [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width
#define PHONE_UISCREEN_IPHONE6          PHONE_UISCREEN_HEIGHT==667.0f .....and out put is (0,0,375,667). So frame for self.view is right but I don't know why this frame is not adjust whole iPhone 6 screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92602/discussion-between-rahul-and-hasan83).