# iOS 9 not showing UIPageViewController full screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode7, uipageviewcontroller

I´m updating and app that it was built using iOS 8 and Xcode 6 to iOS 9 and Xcode 7. The app was working perfectly but now it is not showing my UIPageViewController at full screen in iPhone 6 and iPhone 6s.

It´s strange because for iPhone 5 and below works right. I have set a new default "Launch Screen.storyboard" as Launch Screen File and here is what I get:

[UIPageViewController not showing at full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX81R.png)

I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190593/why-in-ios-9-and-xcode-7-not-show-full-view-height-and-width-in-iphone-6-and-abo) but it seems that there are no right answers.

I followed a tutorial from www.appcoda.com to make  my UIPageViewController and using the code from there https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2857188/PageViewDemo.zip I'm not able to make it work in iPhone 6 and iPhone 6s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the new LauncScreen.storyboard, you are indicating to the OS that you are supporting iPhone6/6+ native resolutions. Check if you are missing autolayout constraints. Refer [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/89816/porting-app-iphone-6-iphone-6-plus-ios-8-top-10-tips) article on how to go about it.

[UPDATED]:

Add constraints to Page Content View Controller as shown below:
[image]

Add launch screen file:
[image]

Select launch screen file in Target>General:
[image]

Enjoy the results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the article, I have followed the main steps including: auto-layout,  the Launch Screen and @x3 images...but still I get the same strange result. I followed this tutorial [link] (http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/) to make  my UIPageViewController and using the code from there [link] (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2857188/PageViewDemo.zip) I'm not able to make it work in iPhone 6 and iPhone 6s. Could someone please help me? Thanks!

Comment: Updated the answer to include exact steps. This fixes the issue as shown in screenshot above.

Comment: I have added the launch screen file and selected it as Launch Screen File under Target>General as you have said, but still the images don´t show at full screen. Is there any other step that I´m missing? Have you resized the images? Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned in original response, you still need constraints to be added. Updated answer to show that.

Comment: I had autolayout enabled and I have tried with your constrains, but still I don´t get the same result as you. Could you please post a link to your xcode project so I can see what I´m doing wrong? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You need to do only the steps mentioned above. Updated solution is available here: https://app.box.com/s/hoyvvfjgrwlhel81ud29eb0iso6h6apv

Comment: The problem that I had was setting the constraints correctly, now it´s working

Answer (score 1):

I checked the PageViewDemo source you provide. You should add this method to your ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
   [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
   self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The method you suggest is not making any difference to the result.